# How to get 3 child array in main array in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

> I need dtbl_collection_0, dtbl_collection_1 and dtbl_collection_3
>   dynamic value get. and also here not fixed 0,1,2,3,4,5,...... here not
>   fixed.

Please, anyone, help me

```
 Array
    (
        [user_ID] => 1
        [action] => editpost
        [originalaction] => editpost
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_type] => datatable
        [original_post_status] => auto-draft
        [cur_jj] => 11
        [hidden_aa] => 2020
        [cur_aa] => 2020
        [hidden_hh] => 09
        [cur_hh] => 09
        [hidden_mn] => 49
        [cur_mn] => 49
        [original_publish] => Publish
        [publish] => Publish
        [dtbl_collection_0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 11
                [1] => 22
                [2] => 33
            )

        [dtbl_collection_1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 44
                [1] => 55
                [2] => 66
            )

        [dtbl_collection_2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 77
                [1] => 88
                [2] => 99
            )

        [post_name] => 
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [ID] => 95
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
    )
```

[image]

```
global $post;   
$dtbl_collection = get_post_meta($post->ID,'dtbl_collection',true);
if($dtbl_collection){       
    foreach ($dtbl_collection as $key => $value) {          

    }   
}
```

> How to dynamic key for 3 array. here is my code how to get this.

Comment: Please add information as text, rather than images. That could have easily been copied an pasted into the question. And your question is unclear, what do you mean by "how to dynamic key"? What are you trying to do? Get values? Insert values? Please add more details.

Comment: ok I will put @El_Vanja

Comment: I have put pls check and help me@El_Vanja

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer here

```
foreach ($dtbl_collection as $key => $value) {
            $strFindMe = "dtbl_collection_";
            $exists = strpos($key, $strFindMe);
            if ($exists !== false) {
                print_r($key);
            }
    }
```